# Call to undefined method Cake\Mailer\Email::setFrom() coming in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, email, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

While using CakePHP email code, I am getting below error:-
    Call to undefined method Cake\Mailer\Email::setFrom()

My CakePHP 3 email code is as below :-

I have added Email Class at the top of Controller
    use Cake\Mailer\Email;

In Controller's method, I am using below code :-

```
$email = new Email('default');
$email->setFrom(['info@example.com' => 'Test Email'])
->setTo('xyz@example.com')
->setSubject('Testing Email !!')
->send('Testing Email with CakePHP 3');
```

Please help me!

Comment: Are you using Cake < 3.1 or the ones after that?

Comment: How can I check exact version?

Comment: Its 3.3.8, I found in vendor\cakephp\cakephp\VERSION.txt

Comment: Check the Configuration of Transport, here you will find more information https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html#configuring-transports

Comment: Show us the whole code of your controller. It might help

Comment: use Cake\Mailer\Email;

public function sendemail(){
   $email = new Email('default');
   $email->setFrom(['info@example.com' => 'Test Email'])
   ->setTo('xyz@example.com')
   ->setSubject('Testing Email !!')
   ->send('Testing Email with CakePHP 3');
}

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is ok!

You can test easily using `var_dump($email)` before instatiate it.

You can check if the method exists on the class:

```
var_dump(method_exists(Cake\Mailer\Email::class, 'setFrom'));
```

Or:

```
var_dump(method_exists($email, 'setFrom'));
```

You also can navigate inside the Cake\Mailer\Email file and look if there is the method.

Comment: bool(false) is coming with var_dump(method_exists(Cake\Mailer\Email::class, 'setFrom'));

Comment: But this returns true ?
$email = new Cake\Mailer\Email();
var_dump(method_exists($email, 'setFrom'));

Comment: Class 'App\Controller\Cake\Mailer\Email' not found is coming but I have added use Cake\Mailer\Email at top;

Answer (score 0):

Yu must use:

```
$email = new Email('default');
$email->from(['info@example.com' => 'Test Email'])
->to('xyz@example.com')
->subject('Testing Email !!')
->send('Testing Email with CakePHP 3');
```